# Hadoop archives - HarFileSystem / HadoopArchives

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Hadoop V1 java api had `HarFileSystem`[1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/HarFileSystem.html) class to archive and access small files in hdfs. I want to use the same feature in current version of hadoop, but cannot find any FileSystem class for the same in the current docs[2](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/index.html). How do I do it using java API?

The command line interface has `hadoop archive` command to do it. Hadoop CLI is a bash script that uses `org.apache.hadoop.tools.HadoopArchives` for the archive command. But there is no info in docs as to how to use this class.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not much but if you import org.apache.hadoop.fs.HarFileSystem you can use it and at least look at the java doc in your IDE.

`FileSystem harFS = HarFileSystem.get(URI.create("/"), conf);`